# How to add header columns in gridview based on SQL query ? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-server-2012

I have a `gridview`.I want to display `QUERY RESULT` in `gridview` header (columns) dynamically.Header shows based on `SQL-QUERY`.
Here is my `SQL-QUERY`
`USE db_compiler SELECT Column_Name FROM tbl_field WHERE Table_Name='pak'`
For example it this return rows `id`,`name`,`city` then i want to these shows in `gridview` header.
How can i do this.
ASPX:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
    <form id="form" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="load" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

ASPX.CS

```
public void load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string tbl_name = Session["value"].ToString();
    //string tbl_name = "new";
    string query = "USE db_compiler SELECT Column_Name FROM tbl_field WHERE Table_Name='pak'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    cnn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    adp.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior when you use `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` is to retrieve the column names from the data source.If it's not showing the column names maybe there's something wrong with your SQL query. The following code works fine:

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        this.GetData();
}

private void GetData()
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, City FROM Cities", connection))
        {
            using (var a = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                connection.Open();
                a.Fill(table);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
   GridView1.DataSource = table;
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

**Output:**

[image: Dynamically display GridView column headers]

Comment: Thanks for response.But you can't understand my question.Actually I'm creating `SQL-EDITOR` and we don't know how many result comes from sql query.Actaully it's column name which user created in table.so i want from this query `USE db_compiler SELECT Column_Name FROM tbl_field WHERE Table_Name='pak'"` this query may rsturn 5 result or may b 10 result or may b 1 result.It's depends on result.and automatically header generate according to query.But You provide me query in which you use `SELECT ID, City FROM Cities`

Comment: I want output in this shape [LINK](http://i.imgur.com/6vlVo3I.jpg) and here is my sql table[SQL-IMG](http://i.imgur.com/DtIsha8.png)

Comment: Your SQL statement is not valid - SELECT Column_Name FROM tbl_field WHERE Table_Name='pak'

Comment: I think its good because it retrieve me all the columns name of table.